# Sort rows with the least NA to the most NA in Unix

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a six columns data frame as below:

```
A   Sample_a    Sample_a,Sample_b   Sample_a,Sample_b,Sample_c
B   Sample_b    Sample_c    NA
C   Sample_c    NA  NA
D   Sample_d    Sample_d,Sample_e   Sample_d,Sample_e,Sample_f
E   Sample_e    Sample_f    NA
F   Sample_f    NA  NA
```

I want to sort the data frame by row with the least NA followed by the most NA. I expect to have an output below:

```
A       Sample_a        Sample_a,Sample_b       Sample_a,Sample_b,Sample_c
D       Sample_d        Sample_d,Sample_e       Sample_d,Sample_e,Sample_f
B       Sample_b        Sample_c        NA
E       Sample_e        Sample_f        NA
C       Sample_c        NA      NA
F       Sample_f        NA      NA
```

However, when I tried to do `sort -r -k3 -r -k4` but it gives me the output below:

```
E   Sample_e    Sample_f    NA
D   Sample_d    Sample_d,Sample_e   Sample_d,Sample_e,Sample_f
B   Sample_b    Sample_c    NA
A   Sample_a    Sample_a,Sample_b   Sample_a,Sample_b,Sample_c
F   Sample_f    NA  NA
C   Sample_c    NA  NA
```

How do I sort the table correctly in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk to count the NAs in the records, output the number and the record, use `sort` and remove the first column with `cut`:

```
$ awk '{tmp=$0; print gsub(/NA/,"NA",tmp),$0 }' file |  # append count of NAs
sort -n |                                               # sort 
cut -d\  -f 2-                                          # remove count
```

Output:

```
A   Sample_a    Sample_a,Sample_b   Sample_a,Sample_b,Sample_c
D   Sample_d    Sample_d,Sample_e   Sample_d,Sample_e,Sample_f
B   Sample_b    Sample_c    NA
E   Sample_e    Sample_f    NA
C   Sample_c    NA  NA
F   Sample_f    NA  NA
```

You may need to tune the delimiters etc. for the commands to your liking but that's the general approach. Also, ATM all `NA` strings are counted which may not be the right thing to do but in the lack of knowing the delimiters in the file, I couldn't (for tab delim for example):

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{c=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="NA")c++;print c,$0}' file | ...
```